# How do I correctly render images via Hotwire Turbo streams?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

My problem: When rendering images using Hotwire/Turbo, all URLs render with host `example.org` instead of my actual hostname. Regular views are fine, but rendering partials through a Turbo stream leads to ActiveStorage URLs like `http://example.org/.../`.

Context: I have a simple Todo app, with a working view, partial, and turbo stream which together show a Todo and a list of associated users. When I join a User to a Todo, the turbo stream renders the correct partial, and puts the user's name and avatar in the DOM where I want. However, the image URL from ActiveStorage contains the `example.org` hostname.

I've set my standard URL options in `config/environments/*.rb`, including `routes.default_url_options[:host]`, and `config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]`. I also learned about the file `config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb`, where you can set an `http_host` parameter; however, I've set `http_host`, the `https` boolean, and still Turbo is rendering my `image_tag` with example.org.

Further, I've found limited advice about how to manipulate the default renderer programmatically (in order to fix the issue). [This source](https://dev.to/mepatterson/getting-rails-applicationcontroller-renderer-to-render-images-and-know-about-the-rack-session-2205) says to grab `ApplicationController.renderer` and override the properties, like so:

```
renderer = ApplicationController.renderer.new(
  http_host: request.host_with_port,
  https: (request.protocol == "https://"),
  "rack.session": request.session
)
```

but the `broadcast_action_to` methods do not appear to accept a `renderer` parameter, so this doesn't actually help me within Turbo.

There must be a configuration that I'm missing, but I'm not finding it in the Turbo or Hotwire documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was missing `config.action_controller.default_url_options`. Once I configured that the same as the other default_url_options, my links began to render properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a dynamic `default_url_options` as my application is multi-tenant so I added this to `ApplicationController`:

```
def default_url_options
  { host: SiteSetting[:entity].domains.first.name, protocol: 'https' }
end
```

I think this all springs from having an `asset_host` configuration in place so that normally image url's have the asset host in them. `ActiveStorage` url's use the current default host (not the asset host of course) because they're actually redirect routes rather than actual files. I'd assume if `asset_host` isn't set, then the image paths would be relative and not absolute? It'd be ideal if they could just be kept relative regardless.